# How to know ephemeral space is mounted or not

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2

I know that there is some ephemeral space is attached to the instance based on instance type. and we need to mount this space at launch time. I want to know is this space is mount or not. Is there any way to get this information?

Answer (score 1):

You can check your [Block Device Mapping](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/UserGuide/block-device-mapping-concepts.html), from the web console, [CLI](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/reference/ec2/describe-instance-attribute.html) or instance metadata. Note that you can specify instance store (a.k.a. ephemeral) volumes for an instance only when you launch it.

As simple way to check if a specific instance has instance store volumes available is consulting the instance metadata service from within the instance itself. Just point a browser or curl to `http://169.254.169.254/latest/meta-data/block-device-mapping/`. You'll see 'ephemeralX' for the ephemeral volumes and 'ami' for the images root device mapping.

Comment: if someone forgot to mount ephemeral space when launchine the instance then how can i know is it(ephemeral space) mounted or not?

Comment: Edited the answer to cover this specifically.